# Firebase DB slow download

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase realtime DB i am using to track user analytics. Currently there is about 11 000 users and each of them has quite a bit of entries ( from ten to few hundreds based on how long they interacted with the app ). Json file is 76MBs when i export whole DB.
I am using this data only for analytics, so i will have a look once per day or so on all of the data. Ie i need to download whole DB to get all the data.

When i do that, it takes about 3-5 minutes to actually load the data. I can imagine that if there were ten times more users, it would not be usable then anymore, because of load time.
So i am wondering if these load times are normal and if this is realy bad practice to do such thing? The reason i always download whole DB, is that i want to get overall data, ie how many users is registered and then for example how many ads were watched. To do that, i need to go into each user and see how many ads he watched and count them up. I cant do that without having access to data of all users.

This is first time i am doing something like this on a bit larger scale and those 76MBs are a bit surprising to me as well as the load times to get the data. It seems like its not feasable long term to use this setup.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need this data yourself, consider using the [automated backups](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/backups) to get access to the JSON. These backups are made out-of-band, meaning that they (unlike your current process) don't interfere with the handling of other client requests.

Additionally, if you're only using the database for gathering user analytics, consider offloading the data to a database that's more suitable for this purpose. So: use Realtime Database for the user's to send the data to you, but remove it from there to a cheaper/better place after that.

For example, it is quite common to transfer the data to BigQuery, which has much better ad-hoc querying capabilities than Realtime Database.